# How to set working/current directory in Vim?

Tags: text-editor, vim

So when I want to create a new file by using the :e command I don't want to specify the whole path, just the new filename.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

As already suggested, you can use autochdir, which will change to the directory of the file you opened, the other option is

```
:cd mydirectory
```

which will change the directory. This can be an absolute or relative path, so `:cd ..` will move up one level. Or you can use `:cd %:h` which will also change to the directory the current file is in, but without setting autochdir.

```
:cd
```

will change directory to your home directory (or on windows, print the current directory).

```
:cd -
```

will change the directory to the previous directory you visited.

Comment: if you're using multiple windows, you can even use :lcd to change directory for the current window only.

Comment: @Useless: interesting... I don't think I'd ever want that, but I suppose that's a matter of taste. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the %:h means, any help?

Comment: @Michael `%` translates to the current file name including path, `:` adds modifier, `h` is head, i.e. the path up to the last path separator, that is excluding the file name itself.

Comment: @falstro, do you know how :cd command can apply to all windows within the same vim running instances? Ex: when using split :sp

Comment: When using multiple tabs, you can use `:tcd` to change directory for the current tab only.

Answer (score 21):

Also if you are browsing the filesystem with the netrw file explorer you can set the current directory by pressing the c key.

Edit: for newer versions try `cd` if `c` doesn't work.

Comment: also use ```set autochdir``` to make the ```'c' key``` take effect in shell, so that you can use ```!command args ``` under changed dir.

Comment: Note that it's changed from `c` to `cd` now.

Answer (score 15):

Try adding `set autochdir` to your `.vimrc`. If you want to change it just this once, use `:cd` (or `:cd!` to force it).

Comment: the help says this breaks some plugins (i don't know which ones) so I've taken the precaution of adding mapping in my .vimrc: `cnoremap cd. lcd %:p:h` and `nnoremap ,cd :cd %:p:h<CR>:pwd<CR>` instead

Comment: also use ```'c' key``` in netrw file explorer to accompany this.

Answer (score 5):

With `netrw:` in addition to pressing the <kbd>c</kbd> key to set the current directory, you may also put:

```
let g:netrw_keepdir= 0
```

in your `.vimrc`; this means that `netrw` will keep the browsing directory the same as the current directory.

Comment: This seems to have an equivalent behavior as :lcd for each netrw folder change.  Do you have an idea how this setting could be the equivalent as a :cd instead (change dir for all windows)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what is wrong with vim. I want the directory where I start up vim as the current.

I have followed the tip about autochd above and set that to noautcd in my .vimrc.

I haven't done it yet, but I am about to start up vim like this from now on:

```
vim —cmd 'cd `pwd`'
```

That will make it stick to the current directory!

Comment: There's a `—` (em-dash) character in your code, you probably mean `--`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to my `.vimrc` automatically changes Vim's working dir to the current file:

```
autocmd BufEnter * silent! :lcd%:p:h
```

Comment: `set autochdir` does that as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Now I just use those code instead of install a plugin

```
" 自动切nvim到当前文件所在路径, 避免leaderF每个命令前都要敲一下 :pwd.
    " 代替autochdir:  Switch to the directory of the current file unless it breaks something.
    au AG BufEnter * call AutoDiR()
    func! AutoDiR()
        " Don't mess with vim on startup.
        let should_cd = (!exists("v:vim_did_enter") || v:vim_did_enter)
                                                  " 或
                                " v:vim_did_enter :
                                "     0 during startup
                                "     1 just before VimEnter.
        "  forbid for some filetypes
            " let should_cd = should_cd && david#init#find_ft_match(['help', 'dirvish', 'qf']) < 0
        " Only change to real files:
        let should_cd = should_cd && filereadable(expand("%"))
                                    " filereadable()
                                            " The result is a Number, which is |TRUE| when a file with the
                                            " name {file} exists, and can be read.
        if should_cd
            silent! cd %:p:h
        endif
    endf

    " cdh:   cd here
    nno cd :cd %:p:h<cr><cmd>pwd<cr><cmd>let g:Lf_WorkingDirectory=getcwd()<cr><cmd>echo "Lf目录:"..g:Lf_WorkingDirectory<cr>
    " nno cdh
    cnorea <expr> cdh ( getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'cdh') ?
                      \ 'cd %:p:h<cr>  :pwd<cr>'
                      \ :  'cdh'


    " 方法2: 不好使? 要敲一次pwd触发?
        " au AG VimEnter * set autochdir | pwd | echom '设置了autochdir'
                                " Note: When this option is on,  some plugins may not work.
    " 貌似不行:
        " Plug 'https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter'


    " 对于vscode-nvim
        " vscode用wsl的nvim作为bin时,pwd永远是Microsoft VS Code.  等邮件通知更新吧. 其实不影响使用?
        " 我的笔记: https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/520#issuecomment-1013853745
        "
        "  这个也不行:
        " au AG BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h
                " lcd: local window cd ?
                "      Like |:cd|, but only set the current directory for the  current window.
```

---

You could install the [Rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter) Vim plugin, which automatically changes the working directory to the automatically-detected project root when you open a file or directory. After Rooter has set the working directory for you, if you try to edit a file like `:e example.txt`, Vim will edit `example.txt` in the project root.

If you’re using the [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) plugin manager, you can install Rooter by adding the following to your `.vimrc`, then reloading Vim and running `:PlugInstall`.

```
Plug 'airblade/vim-rooter'
```

Answer (score 1):

This was solution to my problem when using **Nvim NvChad**.

I did try to use `set autochdir` but that still didn't work.

So next thing I did was set custom mapping.

1. Add to `custom/chadrc.lua` this line of code `M.mappings = require "custom.mappings"`
2. Create new file `mappings.lua` in folder `custom`
3. Add this lines of code to `mappings.lua`

```lua
local M = {}
M.abc = {
    n = {
        ["<leader>cf"] = {"<cmd>cd %:h <CR>", "Set Files Location As Dir"} 
    }
}
return M
```

4. Open nvim and to change dir to current file location press `<leader>cf`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering about `%:h` the relevant Vim help topic is:

```
:help filename-modifiers
```

Once there, if you scroll down, there are several examples that demonstrate the various modifiers.

---

`%` and `#` are a bit further up the page. They're covered at:

```
:help cmdline-special
```

---

- [filename-modifiers | VimHelp.org](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers)
- [cmdline-special | VimHelp.org](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special)