# Make VIM to consider current folder the root

Tags: vim, path, editor

I already know how to quit Vim, now I'm wondering is it possible anyhow to force Vim search '/somedir/file.js' in current directory when you press `gf`, as if it were './somedir/file.js'?

UPD: There's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288756) how to set path in general, but it doesn't help to make `/myfolder/` pointed to some certain folder I want. `/myfolder/` is always absolute path to the root of current volume.

Comment: Maybe this helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288756/how-to-set-working-current-directory-in-vim

Comment: Just delete the first `/`?

Comment: There's another suggestion: to create symlinks in root :) But no, seriously, the question is how to make VIM to consider `/` not root of the volume but project's root (or some other certain folder). Deleting slash in the beginning breaks the project.

Comment: Yeap, @TamásSzabó sent the link that contains your answer: add `set autochdir` to your vimrc.

Comment: @ThiagoMedeiros that's not exactly the case. His root in the path is not the file system root. He wants to set his root to a different root, the web project root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim counts filenames  beginning with `/` as file system  root always, as
you observed.  If that wasn't the  case, of if `'isf'`  (the option that
controls what is  considered file name) accepted a regex,  this would be
easier to solve. But if you remove  `/` from `'isf'` then no slashes are
considered part of a file name anymore.

The only solution  to this I can  think of is using the  visual mode for
`gf`. As you may  know, if you have text selected  visually and use `gf`
then the  visual selection  will be considered,  instead of  the `'isf'`
match. Then all we need to do  is to visually select the file name under
cursor excluding a possible leading `/`. This can be solved in a map, if
you don't mind messing your previous search:

```
nnoremap <silent> gf :let @/ = substitute(expand('<cfile>'), '^/', '', '')
                   \  <bar>normal gngf<cr>
```

This overwrites your `gf` to set the search to the filename under cursor
(`expand()`), minus leading  slash if any (`substitute()`)  and then run
the  normal  commands `gn`  which  selects  the  match and  finally  the
original `gf`.

If you  want to save  your previous search  and restore, you  can easily
create a function to  wrap this all. Note that I also  wrote this is two
lines just because I'm  a declared enemy of long lines.  But if you just
want to test it remove the `\` and write in a single line.

Now your  `gf` will interpret `/file`  as `file`. Thus if  you're on the
correcty directory this will work. If  you need to search in a different
directory, the option you're looking for is [`'path'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'path'), or `'pa'` for
short. You  can give  a list  of directories to  search. Much  like Unix
shell's `$PATH`. Separated by commas. From the help (be sure to read the
rest yourself, with `:h 'pa`):

> This is  a list of directories  which will be searched  when using the
>   `gf`,  `[f`,  `]f`, `^Wf`,  `:find`,  `:sfind`,  `:tabfind` and  other
>   commands, provided  that the  file being searched  for has  a relative
>   path (not  starting with "/", "./"  or "../"). The directories  in the
>   'path' option may be relative or absolute.

In conclusion, to use this in  your project, set your `'path'` if needed
as  you wish  and enable  this map.  Or run  it all  automatically in  a
`:autocmd` or  something similar.  You aren't changing  the root  of the
project as you initially suggested, but you're kind of emulating this by
including the  desired directory  in `'path'` and  then forcing  `gf` to
ignore the leading `/`.

Comment: Happy that it worked @AlexDolgov ! Don't forget to accept the answer as correct if you think the problem is solved ;)